# Java Inter process communication

Tags: java, ant

Good Day Everyone, I have a program (lets call it 'A'), which is called from an ANT script using `java`. This program uses `Runtime.getRunTime.exec("batFile.bat")`. The `.bat` file in-turn calls another java file (lets call it 'B'). Now, here comes the problem.

**Is there a way in which B can access instance variable of A ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the value of the variable in process A before it launches process B, then you could share that value in a number of ways.

Pass it as a command line argument, e.g.:

```
String[] cmd = {"batFile.bat", variableValue};
Runtime.getRunTime.exec(cmd);
```

Set it as variable in the environment of B's process, e.g.:

```
String cmd = "batFile.bat";
String[] envp = {"VARIABLE="+variableValue};
Runtime.getRunTime.exec(cmd, envp);
```

Write the value to a file in process A, read the file in process B.

Comment: +1 for KISS approach - if you just want to pass a value, pass a value 8=}

Answer (score 5):

No. Because the .bat file is creating a new jvm process. May be you want to use DB to share the data.